# Correct the query to fetch data from three different tables

Tags: mysql

I have created following query.

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, aucs.winner_id, aucs.beginner, accounts.user_id
FROM users, aucs, accounts
WHERE users.id
IN (
aucs.winner_id
)
AND users.id NOT 
IN (
accounts.user_id
)
AND aucs.beginner =  '1'
```

I want to select users email addresses which appears only once in aucs table in column winner_id where aucs.beginner should also be equal to '1' and that user id is not available in accounts table. I have written the query which I placed above is not working.

Comment: please post schema of tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from top of my head, you don't need accounts.user_id since you wish to get records where user_id is not present in accounts.

```
SELECT users.id as users_id, users.email, aucs.winner_id, aucs.beginner
FROM users
LEFT JOIN aucs
ON aucs.winner_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN accounts
ON accounts.user_id = users.id
WHERE aucs.beginner = '1' AND accounts.id IS NULL
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(aucs.winner_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        users.id, 
        users.email, 
        aucs.winner_id, 
        aucs.beginner, 
        accounts.user_id
FROM    users
        INNER JOIN aucs 
            ON users.id = aucs.winner_id 
        LEFT JOIN accounts 
            ON aucs.winner_id = accounts.user_id AND 
               aucs.beginner =  '1'
WHERE   accounts.user_id IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thanks this query is good, but this one is showing me users id which are in accounts table also, I need users id which are not in accounts table but in auc table as winner_id where aucs.beginner = '1'